# Remove Parent Array at source (Saving Options to Wordpress)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

***EDIT: Updates added to the bottom.***

I'm submitting an array to be saved as a Wordpress option. I've done some debugging with `print_r`/`var_dump` and can see the array being submitted is wrapped by `Array ( [string] =>`.

Below I have provided a comparison between the saved array and that which is submitted.

I believe this is why the array is not saved correctly. The array is picked up by the Wordpress Simple Settings code using `$_REQUEST`

Ideally I would like to submit this without this wrapper. Alternatively I can amend the [simple-settings class](https://github.com/clifgriffin/wordpress-simple-settings/blob/master/wordpress-simple-settings.php#L129)

### Summary of intent

Allow user to add and remove individual items (using jquery) to an array which is saved in Wordpress options (using wordpress-simple-settings).

[image]

### Resources

- http://jesin.tk/dynamic-textbox-jquery-php/

  - This allows the option to add/remove individual items and then save as an array
- https://github.com/clifgriffin/wordpress-simple-settings

  - Saves these options

#### Saved Array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => woocommerce/woocommerce.php 
    [1] => wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php 
    [2] => usersnap/usersnap.php 
    [3] => video-user-manuals/plugin.php 
    [4] => woodojo/woodojo.php 
    [5] => worker/functions.php 
    [6] => advanced-custom-fields/acf.php 
    [7] => admin-menu-editor-pro/menu-editor.php 
    [8] => image-widget/image-widget.php 
    [9] => bwp-minify/bwp-minify.php 
    [10] => cookies-for-comments/cookies-for-comments.php 
    [11] => debug-bar/debug-bar.php 
    [12] => woocommerce-debug-bar/woocommerce-debug-bar.php 
    [13] => woothemes-updater 
)
```

#### Array being sent to be saved

```
Array ( 
    [string] => Array ( 
        [0] => woocommerce/woocommerce.php 
        [1] => wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php 
        [2] => usersnap/usersnap.php 
        [3] => video-user-manuals/plugin.php 
        [4] => woodojo/woodojo.php 
        [5] => worker/functions.php 
        [6] => advanced-custom-fields/acf.php 
        [7] => admin-menu-editor-pro/menu-editor.php 
        [8] => image-widget/image-widget.php 
        [9] => bwp-minify/bwp-minify.php 
        [10] => cookies-for-comments/cookies-for-comments.php 
        [11] => debug-bar/debug-bar.php 
        [12] => woocommerce-debug-bar/woocommerce-debug-bar.php 
        [13] => woothemes-updater 
) )
```

#### From the Input Form

```
<input type="text" 
    name="<?php echo $Plugin->get_field_name('req_plugins_arr'); ?>[]" 
    value="<?php echo $value; ?>" 
    id="box<?php echo $key+1; ?>" />
```

#### Input form as outputted in browser

```
<form method="post" action="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=bamboo-settings">
        <input type="hidden" id="bamboo_save" name="bamboo_save" value="c8ef4deceb"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=bamboo-settings">

        <table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="my-form">
                    <th scope="row" valign="top">Required Plugins List</th>

                    <td>
                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box1">Plugin <span class="box-number">1</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="woocommerce/woocommerce.php" id="box1"></label> <a href="#" class="add-box">Add More</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box2">Plugin <span class="box-number">2</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value=" wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php" id="box2"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box3">Plugin <span class="box-number">3</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value=" usersnap/usersnap.php" id="box3"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box4">Plugin <span class="box-number">4</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value=" video-user-manuals/plugin.php" id="box4"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box5">Plugin <span class="box-number">5</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
woodojo/woodojo.php" id="box5"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box6">Plugin <span class="box-number">6</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
worker/functions.php" id="box6"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box7">Plugin <span class="box-number">7</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
advanced-custom-fields/acf.php" id="box7"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box8">Plugin <span class="box-number">8</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
admin-menu-editor-pro/menu-editor.php" id="box8"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box9">Plugin <span class="box-number">9</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
image-widget/image-widget.php " id="box9"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box10">Plugin <span class="box-number">10</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
bwp-minify/bwp-minify.php" id="box10"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box11">Plugin <span class="box-number">11</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
cookies-for-comments/cookies-for-comments.php" id="box11"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box12">Plugin <span class="box-number">12</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
debug-bar/debug-bar.php" id="box12"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box13">Plugin <span class="box-number">13</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
woocommerce-debug-bar/woocommerce-debug-bar.php" id="box13"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>

                        <p class="text-box"><label for="box14">Plugin <span class="box-number">14</span> <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]" value="
woothemes-updater" id="box14"></label> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table><input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Save Settings">
    </form>
```

## Updates

A little progress. If I amend the input to:

PHP:

```
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $BambooPlugin->get_field_name('req_plugins_arr', $type = "array"); ?>" value="" id="box1" />
```

HTML OUT:

```
    <input type="text" name="bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][]" value="woothemes-updater" id="box14">
```

If I print_r before the save function I get this array printed out for each entry.

eg.

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d ) 
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d ) 
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d ) 
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d )
```

And then only the final item in the array is saved as

```
    Array ( [0] => d )
```

I think this might need amendments in the save settings (line:129)[https://github.com/clifgriffin/wordpress-simple-settings/blob/master/wordpress-simple-settings.php#L129]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the input form code as displayed in the browser.

Comment: Have done this. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Just spotted the [req_plugins_arr][string][] in the name... I see where this is going. Not sure how to remove from there though.

Comment: That is the [default behavior](https://github.com/clifgriffin/wordpress-simple-settings/blob/master/wordpress-simple-settings.php#L101) of simple settings. Try replacing `get_field_name('req_plugins_arr');` with `get_field_name('req_plugins_arr', 'array');`

Comment: Hi A.Jesin - Made a little progress and have listed this above in updates.

Comment: Try this `<input type="text" name="<?php echo $BambooPlugin->get_field_name('req_plugins_arr', "array"); ?>[]" value="" id="box1" />`. Before trying this get a new copy of the simple settings plugin. It looks like your copy of the plugin has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is actually working there are just a couple of confusing aspects to my framework I'm going to have to clear up. Basically, my attempt to provide data types like string and array is misguided and just causing confusion. This is really just to manage semicolon delimited strings, but I managed to make it confusing and a distraction.

Basically, the proper way to store a true array of values such as you would POST with an HTML form is to just use the default `get_field_name` and then add brackets to indicate it's an array, just like you would with straight HTML.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $BambooPlugin->get_field_name('req_plugins_arr'); ?>[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" id="box<?php echo $key+1; ?>" />
```

The framework does a pretty good job of getting out of your way here. Even though the resulting field name will be `bamboo_setting[req_plugins_arr][string][]`, if you look at the actual handling of "strings", it's a pass through. The raw value is stored with no transformation. And this is the heart of my design flaw...I should have embraced the pass through, just like the underlying WordPress option API, instead of trying to delineate types.

I'll likely change all of the "array" stuff and make it a delimiter handler instead and then keep everything else a straight pass through.

So, conversely, when pulling the data back out, you would just use:

```
$default_plugins = $BambooPlugin->get_setting('req_plugins_arr');
```

This retrieves the raw data with no transformation. If you were to pass array to get_setting in this case, it would bork everything up as it would try to treat it as a delimited string. :-/

I hope this helps...I realize you spent a few days fighting with my framework here so I apologize. That's expressly the opposite of my intention in creating it. I want to save everyone time :)

Comment: It wasn't wasted time. Its the best way to learn. Thanks very much for helping. Will look forward to the updated framework and then post an update here.